# Can my lavender be saved?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

So my lavender plant isn’t looking so good. It is dried out on 3/4 of the plant. Has been this was since Aug.

I think it may have gotten some exposure to roundup through the roots since some weeds were sprayed in the area.

Can it be saved?  Or should it be pulled and replanted?

[image: unhealthy lavander]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sitting here freezing and you've been out playing in your garden?  Life ain't fair!  Grins.  What zone and hemisphere of this planet do you live?

There is a bit of life evident for your lavender.  I would pull this plant up, rip off the dead roots and plant material, plant the live remainder in a one gallon pot of sterilized potting soil.

Glyphosate works primarily by being sprayed or applied to vigorously photosynthesizing leafy plant material. It is then transported to the roots, killing the roots and then the entire plant in 3 weeks.

If you hadn't said glyphosate, your plant is displaying very normal lavender die out. Is this the only lavender?  What other plants are in this bed?  You will need to replace this lavender but it would be nice to know the new lavender will not have the same problem.  Next year, if the bit of lavender you transplanted into a 1 gallon pot in just potting soil thrives, you will be able to add to a lavender 'mass' ??

So if there had been the tiniest bit of wind that day you sprayed, I'll bet your lavender got sprayed.  This is called 'Drift'.  It takes minuscule glyphosate sprayed on leaves to kill a plant.

Glyphosate is only advantageous when needing to kill a large area of weeds.  Should never be used in ornamental plant beds or vegetable gardens.  I only used this for gravel walks and driveways, gravel patios.  Only in the spring after weeds have had a chance to get vigorous but before they go to seed. And on a dead quiet, very warm, still air day.  Sprayer held down very close to the gravel.  It only takes ONE drop of glyphosate (a big drop) to kill a plant whether weed or ornamental or edible.  You do not have to spray till runoff.

Your assessment about your lavender is probably right on.  Glyphosate drift.  If you were thinking there was enough glyphosate sprayed that the roots would take it up I am thinking there was more than enough drift to kill this lavender.

Has it been 3 weeks since you sprayed? How much was sprayed?  Did you soak the soil?

Comment: Haha -- I'm in Napa, CA.  So while there is no snow on the ground, it is 33F this morning...

I sprayed the glyphosate last Summer.  Didn't soak the soil (I don't think!).  Just sprayed a couple of weeds in the general area.  This is along our driveway.  There is actually another lavender about 3 feet from this one that is thriving (the only other plan in that bed).  I'll attempt the lavender surgery that you recommended and see if I can bring this one back to life.

Comment: I'd get at least 3 or 4 more lavenders and plant them offset about 2' apart.  You need to prune these things in the fall cutting all those flower stalks off and leaving your plant looking like an upside down salad bowl.  They make a gorgeous MASS in your landscape.  Remember, what you are looking at is NORMAL for lavenders.  That is why when making a mass or informal hedge of them you want to offset and be more organic in your arrangement so when one or two die like this, it won't be obvious.

Comment: Yeah I agree with the above, its an example of spray drift- I would either take cuttings- long and time consuming process, or basically dig up and start again, those plants are fairly cheap and common enough in shops to buy every year. However if you must spray, cover your plants with something throwaway, like a piece of cardboard when you use weed killer or do it in the evening, when temperatures are lower and wind is slower- or paint the weeds individually rather than blanket spraying.

Comment: The best thing to do is learn how to choose battles.  Weeds are so far down the bottom of my worry list with plants, it is actually funny. In my entire career spanning 40 plus years, I've only tried glyphosate  3 or 4 times to use commercially. Weeds are no problem, so many easy peasy ways to control.  Glyphosate, just one little drop on the foliage of an annual or tender perennial is enough to kill it.  Can damage larger more woody plants.  Weeds are getting too much negative publicity.  The easiest part of gardening is controlling weeds.   Forget using pesticides.  Make even worse problems.

Comment: Blanket spraying combined with glyphosate gives me the willies.  Not good at all for homeowners.  Us experts knew the risks,(killing your client's new pansies costs big bucks) and the risk never helped to make glyphosate useful even in the real world.  Far easier ways to deal with weeds, yawn!  Grins.